# In Altair/Vega-lite how to show percentage of grouped category instead of total?

Tags: data-science, data-visualization, altair

Newbie using Altair/Vega-lite and struggling a bit to "get" the transformations and calculations and encoding way of thinking, especially for more complex/nested data.

Specifically, I am trying to create a super simple layered histogram, that shows the salary distribution of different countries.

So far I was able to get on the Y Axis the percentage of occurrences compared to the total:

```
salaries = {
    'NL': np.random.normal(loc=80000, scale=30000, size=(500,)),
    'ES': np.random.normal(loc=80000, scale=30000, size=(50,))
}
source = pd.DataFrame({k:pd.Series(v) for k,v in salaries.items()})

c = alt.Chart(source).transform_fold(
   ['NL', 'ES'],
   as_=['Benchmark', 'Salaries']
   ).transform_joinaggregate(
       total='count(*)',
       groupby=['Benchmark']
   ).transform_calculate(
       pct='1/ datum.total'
   ).mark_bar(opacity=0.3, binSpacing=0
   ).encode(
       alt.Color('Benchmark:N'),
       x=alt.X('Salaries:Q', bin=alt.Bin(maxbins=20)),
       y=alt.Y('sum(pct):Q', axis=alt.Axis(format='%'), stack=None)
   )
```

which results in:

[total percentage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o2Vv.png)

However, I'd like the percentage to be applicable to each category instead of the total. So, in this example, on the Y axis the second distribution should show percentages in the same level as the first one, as they are identical normal distributions.

I hope it's clear enough, apologies for probably lacking the statistical theory and glossary to explain things better.

Answer (score 2):

It is grouped per category but the problem here is that your 'ES' column has 450 nan values, which are still counted in the `count()` I guess, so your % for the actual values is very low.
One way to solve this is to use `alt.Chart(source.dropna())`. which would yield the plot below.
[image: plot]

Comment: ah that makes perfect sense @debbes, your suggestion works! I was quite confused why the groupby was not really doing what I expected, it makes sense if the nan were being counted, of course! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, after trying it out and looking at the data, won't dropna() remove all records which have nan? So, in this case, all records of 'NL' in rows where the 'ES' column would be nan would also be removed.

Comment: you sent me on the right track :) I had a look at the supported aggregation operations here: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/aggregate.html#ops , and changing the total=count(*) to total=valid(Salaries) seems to have done the trick!